# How do I remove the Title "Languages" from the Language Icon Module?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am trying to create a bilingual site from a Drupal 7 site that already exists in English. I have absolutely no programming background, yet have managed to make it quite far thanks to reading other individuals' questions and answers on Drupal Answers. Thanks guys!

Now I have some questions of my own :) For these questions the page I am referring to is http://laidea.us/testingpage

1. I would like to remove the title "Languages" or "Idiomas" (in Spanish) from the Language Switcher block. I tried seeing if I could do that in views, but couldn't find the Language Switcher block there.
2. I would like to have my language icons be side by side, and without the list bullets next to them.
3. I've noticed that it says what language the content is in, and there is a language switch below my text. How do I get rid of/ hide these fields?

Thank you for your help!

-Jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

previous answer is correct, you need CSS styling. 
The reason that I provide another answer is because you said you have no programming background, so I guess you don't know where to copy-paste the correct code. So here is what you can do:

- download the module  [css injector](https://drupal.org/project/css_injector)
- enable the module
- go to configuration -> development -> css injector (admin/config/development/css-injector)
- create a new rule and give a name to the rule: e.g. front-page styling
- Finally in this rule write your CSS. (here paste the code provided by Елин Й.) 
  **EDIT**: if you can't find a way to remove the LANGUAGE title, there is a quick and dirty solution: add the following:

  ```
  #block-locale-language-content h2 {display: none;}
  ```

If you want to style your website, you really **need to** study a bit CSS, which is very easy and not like difficult programming. You just target(select) the correct things, the styling of which you would like to change, and then apply some changes to them. It's really simple, don't be afraid of it!

for example

```
li {
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

would select all the lists in a website (like the language lists) and make the color blue and the background color red :)

To recap:

- study a bit CSS, [official and good place to learn](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) or for example [here - a bit more fun](http://www.codecademy.com)
- install [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) in order to correctly select what you want to style

Comment: Thank you so much Vagelis! I know a bit about CSS, it was accessing the style sheet that I was unclear about it and the CSS injector module is perfect for that! Quick follow up question. Do you know why the language still displays below the text? How can I remove that?

Comment: Found the answer! http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/how-to-remove-language-indicator-in-content-region

Answer (score 3):

To remove the title 'Languages', configure the block, and set the title as `<none>`

To have the icons side by side and remove the list bullets you need to specify some css in your theme:

```
section.block .content .language-switcher-locale-url li {
  background: none; // in your case, you have background set
  display: inline-block; // to make them side by side
  list-style-type: none; // to get rid of listing bullets
}
```